# How is deployment address chosen (by Parity)?

Tags: parity, contract-deployment, accounts

I am deploying a contract from a Parity instance that has several accounts within it.  When I deploy a contract at the console of the same computer, Parity UI asks me for a password to unlock the account.

And then sometimes when I add a new account, it asks for this password instead.

How does Parity choose which account to debit to deploy from (or is this an ETH thing and not Parity specific)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Parity sets the last account created as the default account.  If you do not specifically set the address to spend from when you deploy the contract (send the transaction) then it should default to the last account created.

A deeper discussion can be found at
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/3135

EDIT:

Looks like there isn't much to that issue page actually.  I checked out command line options at https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Configuring-Parity , but didn't see anything for assigning a default account in the 'Account Options' section.  Regardless it should be the last account that was created.

Comment: Going a little deeper, do you know how to manually specify the address to spend from?

Comment: Not in Parity, I use geth.  You could always open an issue on Parity's github though.  Somebody there will have a much more precise answer.